# Quiz app with different views

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I need to create quiz app with 4 possible screens (image + text, only text..). After I click Start button I need to open not random, but exact view (I get this info from API).

Which is the best way to organize it? Collection View with 4 cells? Or 4 view controllers with segues between them? Or is there anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there are 4 different entry points into your app. So the way I would use is to create 4 different designated `view controllers` because it would be much easier to manage rather than switching back and forth with collection view cells.

But that really depends on how you would want the 4 screens to present to the user, if they all full screen views, `view controllers` would be the better choice for you.

Comment: @kviki happy to help! Good luck on your quiz app